# Where does the Quantum single-particle Lagrangian come from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Mahan's many body physics the Lagrangian is simply given as
$$L=i\hbar\psi^\dagger\psi-\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla\psi^\dagger\cdot\nabla\psi-U(\textbf{r},t)\psi^\dagger\psi$$
I'm trying to derive it from assumptions, but I'm not quite sure whether my method is correct.  I've attempted to come to this by comparing the Euler-Lagrange equation to the Equation of motion, but I still feel a bit uncomfortable with my derivation, i.e. I think there are some errors that I cannot see.  The main two things I'm not sure about is whether I can have the measurement "built in" to the Euler-Lagrange equation (all the partial derivatives are w.r.t. the image of a vector), as well as whether or not I can split the expectation value of the Laplacian.  My method is as follows

> For a free particle, we have
> \begin{equation*}
>   -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|{\psi}\rangle =\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2|{\psi}\rangle 
>  \end{equation*}
> which has a particle density given by
> \begin{equation*}
>   -i\hbar\langle {\psi}|\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|{\psi}\rangle =\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\langle {\psi}|\nabla^2|{\psi}\rangle 
>  \end{equation*}
> We want our Lagrangian density to return this from its equation of motion.  Since we are considering the density, all the elements of the Lagrangian must be in the form of a C number, so wavefunctions always occur in conjugate pairs.  For the quantum case, the only things we can measure are the momentum and the time evolution of the wave-function.  As such, by acting on the wave function by the Lagrangian, we have
> \begin{equation*}
>   \begin{split}
>    &\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\cdot\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\psi}}\\
>    &\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial\psi/\partial x_\mu)}\right)
>   \end{split}
>  \end{equation*}
> taking the densities of these operators, we see that the LHS gives
> \begin{equation*}
>   -i\hbar\psi^\dagger\dot{\psi}=-\psi^\dagger\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\psi}}\right)
>  \end{equation*}
> where the negative sign is a result of the term's placement in the equation of motion.  In order to retain the time derivative on the LHS, the term in brackets must be a C number, so this gives the term
> \begin{equation*}
>   L=i\hbar\psi^\dagger\dot{\psi}+f(\nabla\psi)
>  \end{equation*}
> Likewise, for momentum
> \begin{equation*}
>   \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}(\langle{\psi}|\nabla)\cdot(\nabla|{\psi}\rangle)=\langle{\psi}|\nabla\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\nabla\psi)}\right)
>  \end{equation*}
> which on inspection gives
> \begin{equation*}
>   \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\nabla\psi)}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla\psi
>  \end{equation*}
> which would give (remembering that $|\nabla\psi|^2=(\nabla\psi^\dagger)(\nabla\psi)$)
> \begin{equation*}
>   L=i\hbar\psi^\dagger\psi-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(\nabla\psi^\dagger)(\nabla\psi)
>  \end{equation*}

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. The equation of motion from varying $\psi^\dagger$ in Mahan's lagrangian is just the single-particle Schroedinger equation. That's all that he is saying. I do not see why you are introducing bra and ket vectors.

Comment: @mikestone, I know Mahan uses it to re-introduce the Schrodinger equation, but it seems quite strange he just produces this equation out of nowhere, and I was trying to derive its form using the same method as the classical lagrangian.

Comment: In general there is no unique lagrangian for given equation of motion, so if you start from the Schroedinger equation you cannot "derive" Mahan's action. His choice  is just the most obvious one that works.

Comment: @mikestone so I was trying to come at this from the perspective of classical mechanics, where the form of the lagrangian comes from some axioms (homogeneity and isotropy of space, and homogeneity of time), with the restriction that it matches up with $F=ma$ when put through the Euler-Lagrange equation, are you saying this method doesn't work for Quantum?